# Regarding groupnotation and spacing

Tags: spacing

(G, *) is certainly an acceptable notation for a group. However, I prefer the notation [image]. As you can see, the distance between the letters and brackets are uncomfortably long. Is there a way to shorten the distance?

Comment: `${<}G,*{>}$` should do

Comment: Rather use `$\langle G,* \rangle$` and wrap it up in a macro.

Comment: Here is a range of options: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\Langle{\stretchrel{{<}}{\strut}}
\def\Rangle{\stretchrel{{>}}{\strut}}
\begin{document}
${<}G,*{>}$ $\langle G,* \rangle$ $\Langle G,* \Rangle$
\end{document}`

Comment: Your first option worked brilliantly, I will keep the second one in mind in case I would ever need to expand my knowledge of LaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

However you end up deciding, you might like to use `DeclarePairedDelimiter` from the [`mathtools`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathtools) package

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\group}{<}{,*{>}}
```

This will allow you to make your choice in one go, and you can continue typesetting your document without worrying :)

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\group}{<}{,*{>}}

\begin{document}

$\group{G}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are various options.  The first was closest to your original question.  The second is advocated by Werner's comment.  The third and fourth are homemade versions in which the `<` and `>` are either stretched vertically or scaled with a maximum width constraint of 1ex.  In both these latter cases, the size is set to span the vertical range of a `\strut`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\Langle{\stretchrel{{<}}{\strut}}
\def\Rangle{\stretchrel{{>}}{\strut}}
\def\LLangle{\scalerel[1ex]{{<}}{\strut}}
\def\RRangle{\scalerel[1ex]{{>}}{\strut}}
\begin{document}
${<}G,*{>}$ $\langle G,* \rangle$ $\Langle G,* \Rangle$ $\LLangle G,* \RRangle$
\end{document}
```

[image]

And as Werner suggested, if you use your notation a lot, wrapping it in a macro makes sense, regardless of which option you choose.